# Fragment is not showing up in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Trying to add Fragment to my Activity, but it isn't showing up.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WeatherFragment mainFragment = new WeatherFragment();
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.main_weather_container, mainFragment)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

And there is my fragment:

```
public class WeatherFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        boolean isAttachedToParent = false;
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_weather_fragment, container, isAttachedToParent);
    return inflatedView;
}
}
```

R.id.main_weather_container - FrameLayout in my MainActivity.
R.layout.main_weather_fragment - Fragment's layout
What am i doing wrong?
I've tried to use FragmentActivity + v4 support fragment and fragmentSupportManager, but it didn't make any difference.

MainActivity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_weather_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_16_dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/words_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATED: The problem wasn't in fragment transaction or whatever, i've used tools: namespace that's why fragment wasn't displayed. Sorry about that :(

Comment: Please show your xml where you want to add fragment

Comment: use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: i've mentioned that support fragment manager doesn't help

Comment: can you post your activity main xml

Comment: Uploaded activity xml

Comment: Your `recyclerview` may be inside the layout file of fragment.

Comment: In your MainActivity.xml, try assigning this id : android:id="@+id/main_weather_container  , to  your RecyclerView.

Comment: I'm trying to add fragment to the FrameLayout, what is the sense of adding an id to RecyclerView? It's dummy, i can completely remove it and the logic still remains the same

Comment: How are you determining that the `Fragment` is not being added? Does the `FrameLayout` show as expected? What's in the `main_weather_fragment` layout? What happens if you change its background color?

Comment: I pasted your code in my local . works fine (I used getSupportFragmentManager)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are using `AppCompatActivity` but using `getFragmentManager`.
With `AppCompatActivity` you will need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` rather than `getFragmentManager()`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WeatherFragment mainFragment = new WeatherFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction() 
            .add(R.id.main_weather_container, mainFragment)
            .commit(); 
    } 
}
```

Your `WeatherFragment` should be extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_weather_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_16_dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/words_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Added `WeightSum` in the parent Layout.

Comment: I've mentionetd that it doesn't make any difference, i've already tried it

Comment: and make sure your fragment is extending the support fragment class

Comment: It is extending support class, and support fragment manager, but it still doesn't work

Comment: i've checked it, but unfortunately my app still has blank screen without fragment :(

Comment: Try to remove recyclerview and make container height as match parent

Comment: Ok while fragment view inflation pass null instead of container and dont call super.onCreateView()

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WeatherFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_weather_fragment, null, false);
    return inflatedView;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this way .in your activity call fragment

```
 Fragment fragment = Video_fragment.newInstance();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.framecontainer, fragment).commit();
```

in fragment class.

```
public class Video_fragment extends Fragment{
    View view;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Video_fragment fragment = new Video_fragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_frag, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a instance of `Fragment` in `WeatherFragment`:

```
public static WeatherFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    WeatherFragment weatherFragment = new WeatherFragment();
    weatherFragment.setArguments(args);
    return weatherFragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
}
```

Inside your `Activity` in `MainActivity` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WeatherFragment weatherFragment = WeatherFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.flContainerId, weatherFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Your layout file will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/flContainerId"/>
```